# how to create custom progress bar with circles in android

Tags: android

I am working on an app in which I want to show a ProgressBar, but I want to replace the default Android ProgressBar.

[custom progressbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98bxj.png)

how to create this progressbar. i tried alot but cant do it.
it should increse with button click
if i could apply animation it would be better
thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you use in library [custom progress bar](https://github.com/ashutiwari4/ProgressNevigationBar)

Add ProgressBar to your gradle

```
  compile 'com.ashutosh.progress-nevigation-bar:library:1.0.0'
```

xml:

```
<com.library.NavigationBar
    android:id="@+id/navBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:padding="6dp"
    app:central_line_height="1dp"
    app:enable_border="true"
    app:only_border="false"
    app:tab_border_color_array="@array/border_state_colors"
    app:tab_color_array="@array/indicator_colors"
    app:tab_indicator_color="@color/darkYellow"
    app:tab_padding="48dp"
    app:tab_strok_width="3dp"
    app:tab_text_color_array="@array/text_state_colors"
    app:tab_text_size="18sp"/>
```

and java:

```
NavigationBar bar = (NavigationBar) findViewById(R.id.navBar);
    bar.setOnTabSelected(this);
    bar.setOnTabClick(this);

    bar.setTabCount(count);
    bar.animateView(3000);
    bar.setCurrentPosition(pos);
```